# What's the difference between `` and $()?

Tags: bash, shell

When you want to return a command line output, you may consider using two methods: `` `cat file` `` or `$(cat file)`. As far as I know, they are equivalent before my eyes.

Is there a difference between both? If so, what's the difference please?